# PowerShell script to remove existing DNS entries and setting new entry on Alternative Preferred DNS on NIC card

Tags: powershell, dns, powershell-2.0

```
$net = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=$true -ComputerName . |
       Select-Object -Property [a-z]* -ExcludeProperty IPX*,WINS* |
       Where-Object {$_.DNSServerSearchOrder -like "10.*"}
$num = $net.DNSServerSearchOrder
$num.Length
for ($i=0; $i -lt $num.Length; $i++) {
    if(Test-Connection $num[$i] -Count 1 -ErrorAction silentlycontinue) {
    } else {
        $net.SetDNSServerSearchOrder[$i]"<correct IP>"
    }
}
```

I am not sure if the above code is getting me on a write path or not. I am trying to build up a code for approximately 13000+ servers where we need to check if the DNS configured on the server is a correct or not.

For this I have taken a test server where I am trying to put on some code which will first go to the NICs which are enabled and then will check if the DNS is configured or not. In the `for` loop I am iterating till the length of DNS array. Inside for loop I have aligned if the ping test of the DNS entries. If the DNS ping it do not have to perform anything else need to remove all DNS and set only secondary DNS as primary is working fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Side note: using `Get-WmiObject -ComputerName .` is pointless. The cmdlet will query the local computer by default.

Comment: Thank you Ansgar Yes I am testing on a test machine.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/setdnsserversearchorder-method-in-class-win32-networkadapterconfiguration). `SetDNSServerSearchOrder()` is a method, not a property. You call it with an array of the DNS server IP addresses you want configured.

```
$newNameserver = '8.8.4.4'
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'IPEnabled=True' |
    ForEach-Object {
        $dnsServers = $_.DNSServerSearchOrder[0], $newNameserver
        $_.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($dnsServers)
    }
```

Adjust the filter (and DNS server list) to match your requirements.

Checking whether the already configured IP addresses respond to ping is pointless. Either they are the correct name servers, then the addresses shouldn't be changed even if they're (temporarily) unreachable, or they're not the correct name servers, then you need to define the correct ones anyway.

Comment: We have many other DNS entries in our domain, so I need to keep the first entry as it is and need to update secondary entry and remove all other entries. I have tested first ping when i=0 that would skip the first IP, however when i=1 it should go to else and then remove the IPs of num[$i=1,2,3...] and get a new IP on num[$i=1] restIPs should be removed.

Comment: @IshanSharma So, essentially you want to keep the first name server, change the second, and remove everything else?

Comment: That's correct.. This is what I am was trying to explain :D

Comment: Here is what I am trying to do:

when i=0, "if" condition gets true it would do nothing.
when i =1, "if" condition gets true it would do nothing and if it fails that would skip to "else" should remove the IPs of num[$i=1] firstly and give a new IP on num[$i=1].
when i=2, "if" condition gets true it would do nothing and if it fails it should be removed. So everytime after first two iterations i.e. when i=2,3.4..., if the IP pings it should not perform anything and if the ping status fails it should only remove the IPs.

Comment: I have a query below line would be for all the NICs which are enabled right? What if we have many NICs and instead the query should first check the DNS IP if configured on enabled NIC and if true further performs the task?
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'IPEnabled=True'

Comment: @IshanSharma My recommendation is "don't do that". In case that wasn't clear enough before. If you need to configure DNS on thousands of computers: Make sure you know their network ranges (make a list). Make sure which name servers are the correct ones for each network range (make a list). Make sure you know how to identify network interfaces you want reconfigured. Then, and only then, write a script that updates the identified interfaces with the name servers from the list you created. Do not fiddle around with name server settings dynamically. This is my final response.